# Turn zero filled numbers into whole numbers

Tags: php, numbers, printf

I have a selection of nubmers which are prefixed with zeros to give them a set length.

```
0001,0230,1000,0007,0300
```

How could I make these whole number? So that the resulting numbers are

```
1,230,1000,7,300
```

I was using `sprintf("%04d", $input);` to generate the numbers, is there a reverse of this?

Thanks

Comment: `$input = $input + 0;` as an alternative to the better solutions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel safe that you have numbers and not another kind of string, you can just cast to integer:

```
(int) $num;
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/VQrA50fK

Just be aware that a non-integer (like a string with letters) will cast to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function. Just pass them in and they'll be converted to ints. You can then append them to a sting to make them strings again.

Comment: I guess it depends on if OP has strings or not, as `0230` will intval to `152`, but `'0230'` will work`...

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yeah they are strings, they're coming from a str_replace() function. I should had specified that in the question.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - If they weren't strings, there wouldn't be a problem because it would automatically drop the zeros.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - I mean for the OP, if he was trying to output those numbers using their integral versions (not my posted function) it would drop the zeros automatically. Also, he did mention using `sprintf();` to generate the values which returns a string.